# How do you SetMaxAttachmentSize in TFS 2010?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I want to set the maximum work item attachment size. From old blogs I have found that it is possible by calling `SetMaxAttachmentSize`, but the blogs are for older versions of TFS. I have found the new webservice path for TFS 2010.

```
http://localhost:8080/tfs/_tfs_resources/WorkItemTracking/v1.0/ConfigurationSettingsService.asmx/SetMaxAttachmentSize
```

Unfortunately when I call it like that I receive this error: `This request can only be made against a project collection. The (.asmx) file should be located in the project directory (usually _tfs_resources under the application root).`

I don't know how to format the call via a browser to target a specific project collection. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that this works. It is easier than writing code.

1. Go to this url replacing `<Collection>` with your project collection: `http://localhost:8080/tfs/<Collection>/WorkItemTracking/v1.0/ConfigurationSettingsService.asmx`
2. Choose `SetMaxAttachmentSize`

You can test to make sure you set it correctly by going to the same url above and then selecting `GetMaxAttachmentSize`.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently SetMaxAttachmentSize web service was not leveraged on TFS 2010 therefore you need to do this programmatically, try running the following code:

```
TeamFoundationServer tfs = TeamFoundationServerFactory.GetServer(@"http://yourtfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection");
            ITeamFoundationRegistry rw = tfs.GetService<ITeamFoundationRegistry>();
            RegistryEntryCollection rc = rw.ReadEntries(@"/Service/WorkItemTracking/Settings/MaxAttachmentSize");
            RegistryEntry re = new RegistryEntry(@"/Service/WorkItemTracking/Settings/MaxAttachmentSize", "20971520");  //20MB
            if (rc.Count != 0)
            {
                re = rc.First();
                re.Value = "20971520";
            }
            rw.WriteEntries(new List<RegistryEntry>() { re });
```

I hope it works for you

Regards,
Randall Rosales